# Printf printing garbage after read() call. The offset is always printed as 0

Tags: c, file, printf, offset, lseek

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    int file;
    off_t offset;

    if((file=open("testfile.txt",O_RDONLY)) < -1)
            return 1;

    char buffer[19];

    if(read(file,buffer,19) != 19)  return 1;
    fprintf(stdout,"%s\n",buffer);


    if(offset = lseek(file,-19,SEEK_END) < 0) return 1;
    fprintf(stdout,"%jd\n",(intmax_t)offset);

    if(read(file,buffer,19) != 19)  return 1;
    fprintf(stdout,"%s\n",buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

The Output is as follows:

This is a test file��

0

his is a test file

��

testfile.txt :

This is a test file Testing how SEEK_END works This is a test file

I have tried different formatting for offset, such as %ld,%d, but the output is still the same.
Can't figure out why garbage appears at the end of first line and last line. Please help.

Comment: You don't null terminate your strings.

Comment: I have to specifically use open() system call and use the fd to make other system calls and pass it around. The project I'm working on deals with reading and writing to a binary file and share it across diff processes. I dont want to make the code messy by including fopen()s where open() is used almost everywhere. Hence,stuck with open.

Answer (score 3):

You need to leave room for an end of line character, '\0';

So make `char buffer[19];` `char buffer[20];` then also add `buffer[19] = '\0';` - remember it's zero based counting. Then it shouldn't have the garbage data.

The reason is because printf doesn't know where the end is of the character array. So it keeps printing until it finds a '\0' in garbage memory.

Answer (score 2):

read does not know anthing about strings, it reads bytes from a file. so if you read in 19 bytes into "buffer" and there is no terminating \0 then it is not a valid string.

So either you need to ensure that your buffer is 0 terminated or print out only the first 19 bytes e.g. `printf( "%.*s", sizeof(buffer), buffer );` or extend the buffer for the \0 e.g. `char buffer[20] = {0};`

You should also open the file like this in order to make sure lseek works (file must be opened in binary mode)

```
if((file=open("testfile.txt",O_RDONLY|O_BINARY)) == -1) // returns -1 by failure
{
  perror("testfile.txt"); // to get an error message why it failed.
  return 1;
}
```

it is always good to give an error message when something fails instead of just terminating the program.

Comment: I tried both and it works fine. Thanks a lot. But still unable to figure out why offset is printed as 0. Since it is reading correctly both times, I am guessing it is only a problem with the printing scheme.What could be the problem?

Comment: @ShravanB you reposition the file pointer to the start of the file by writing `lseek(file,-19,SEEK_END)` so it is correct that offset is returned as 0, -19 is relative end of file.

Comment: Actually it was printing 0, no matter where I lseek into. I chose a bad example I guess. The actual problem was with the incorrect use of brackets which another answer pointed out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have already offered solutions for the problem with printing `buffer`. This answer addresses the other question in your post.

Due to operator precedence, the line

```
if(offset = lseek(file,-19,SEEK_END) < 0) return 1;
```

is equivalent to:

```
if(offset = (lseek(file,-19,SEEK_END) < 0)) return 1;
```

I am sure you meant to use:

```
if( (offset = lseek(file,-19,SEEK_END)) < 0) return 1;
```

Comment: Knew I was missing something simple. Thanks a lot for this. Should be more careful with brackets.